# appengine: how to not get a certificate warning with backend secure connection?

Tags: google-app-engine, https, backend

We can activate secure connection for backends but as oppose to front-end we get this certificate warning: (is there a solution to no get this warning?)

This is probably not the site that you are looking for!

You attempted to reach backend.xxxx.appspot.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.appspot.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of requestprocessor.qminer-trial.appspot.com.
You cannot proceed because the website operator has requested heightened security for this domain.

Help me understand
When you connect to a secure website, the server hosting that site presents your browser with something called a "certificate" to verify its identity. This certificate contains identity information, such as the address of the website, which is verified by a third party trusted by your computer. By checking that the address in the certificate matches the address of the website, it is possible to verify that you are securely communicating with the website that you intended and not a third party (such as an attacker on your network).

In this case, the address listed in the certificate does not match the address of the website that your browser tried to go to. One possible reason for this is that your communications are being intercepted by an attacker who is presenting a certificate for a different website, which would cause a mismatch. Another possible reason is that the server is set up to return the same certificate for multiple websites, including the one you are attempting to visit, even though that certificate is not valid for all of those websites. Google Chrome can say for sure that you reached *.appspot.com, but cannot verify that that is the same site as requestprocessor.qminer-trial.appspot.com which you intended to reach. If you proceed, Chrome will not check for any further name mismatches.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7288

It's a limitation of SSL and browser implementations: [Wildcard subdomains on appengine over https on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722397/wildcard-subdomains-on-appengine-over-https-on-firefox)

The workaround, [as per docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs), is to use `-dot-` in place of dots in your subdomain name: `subdomain-dot-domain.appspot.com`

This surely works for subdomains (tested), but I'm not sure if it works for backend domains. Please test it and let us know.

**Update:**

I tested this on one of my test backends (forgot it's still up) and it works as expected with the `-dot-` workaround.