# Google Appengine redirecting to weird url

Tags: google-app-engine

Recently when I have been handshaking(oauth flow) with facecbook, when the callback returns google is sending it to : `http://<version>-dot-<app_id>.appspot.com`

I send out a callback in the form `https://<app_id>.appspot.com/bah/facebook_callback` and it comes back as  `http://<version>-dot-<app_id>.appspot.com/bah/facebook_callback`

Previously it was working fine, no code changes what so ever.. is this SDK 1.6.6 related?

Does anyone know why, or can explain to me how to not allow this to happen ?

Comment: how do you 'interact' with facebook? what is the domain/url you set on your facebook app? what is the callback url you are sending when contacting fb?

Comment: See above.  Its all done using graph api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE actually maps this Urls to the same instance: `http://<version>-dot-<app_id>.appspot.com` maps same way as `http://<version>.<app_id>.appspot.com`

This is being done to work around some browser limitation on wildcard SSL certificates: certificate for `*.domain.com` will not be allowed by browsers for domain `*.*.domain.com`

So Google maps `*.*` to `*-dot-*` as a workaround and uses alternative notation during QAuth process.

See this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs

And this: [Wildcard subdomains on appengine over https on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722397/wildcard-subdomains-on-appengine-over-https-on-firefox/10284023#10284023)