# Security Error in google app Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, browser

i am trying to make an application in google app engine
i am trying to authenticate a user in my google app.
it is working perfectly but when i enter user name and password of a user browser shows me a warning
This is probably not the site you are looking for!

You attempted to reach www.onemoredemo.appspot.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.appspot.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of www.onemoredemo.appspot.com.
You cannot proceed because the website operator has requested heightened security for this domain.

here is my servlet code

```
public class HelloWorld9Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        OAuthConsumer consumer;
        OAuthProvider provider;
        provider=new DefaultOAuthProvider("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",)
        ;
         signer = new OAuthHmacSigner();

                 signer.clientSharedSecret = Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET;

    consumer=new DefaultOAuthConsumer(Constants.CLIENT_ID,Constants.CLIENT_SECRET);

    String redirect_uri="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id="+
            Constants.CLIENT_ID+"&redirect_uri="
            +Constants.REDIRECT_URL+"&response_type="
            +Constants.response_type+"&scope="
            +Constants.SCOPE;


        resp.sendRedirect(redirect_uri);


    }
```

for redirecting him to google authentication page can any one please tell why i am getting this warning and how to remove this.
you can see the demonstration i hosted this app on onemoredemo.appspot.com

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard https certificate that google uses covers `*.appspot.com` and `*.*.appspot.com`, but not all browsers accept this. Some browsers (notably Firefox) complains about using `*.*.appspot.com` certificate.

See: [Wildcard subdomains on appengine over https on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722397/wildcard-subdomains-on-appengine-over-https-on-firefox)

Which browser are you using?

**Edit:**

Solutions:

1. Use [ssl with custom domain](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl), i.e. `www.onemoredemo.com`
2. Use only domain matching `*.appspot.com`, i.e. `onemoredemo.appspot.com`
3. Use [alternate hostname notation as described in docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs): replace `.` with `-dot-`, i.e. use `www-dot-onemoredemo.appspot.com`

Comment: i tried chrome and mozilla both.both are complaining.please tell how to remove this warning

Comment: Edited to add possible solutions