# Google App Engine custom domains, subdomains and SSL

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, wildcard-subdomain

I'm looking to give my `GAE` app a custom domain. Would I still be able to use wildcard subdomains in the same way I am now with the `myapp.appspot.com` domain?

For example, if I navigate to `wildCardSub.myapp.appspot.com` I am able to grab the wildcard subdomain and `SSL` all works fine without any problems.

If I were to change to a custom domain and navigate to `wildCardSub.myNewDomain.com`, would everything work the same? What about `SSL`? Would I have to set anything other than the custom domain up?

I was looking to set up a similar structure to `appspot.com`, where each user is just given a subdomain of the main domain. For example `userName.myDomain.com`.

Any insight is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes you will be able to use subdomains with [wildcard mapping](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain#more_about_wildcard_subdomain_mapping). Note that subdomain name has to match version name.
2. You will need to have proper SSL certs, for specific subdomains. Double subdomain certs, e.g. `*.*.domain.com`, are [not supported by browsers anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722397/wildcard-subdomains-on-appengine-over-https-on-firefox). Single wildcard certs are ok.
3. AFAIK, you can not "move" subdomain to top level, e.g. `wildCardSub.myNewDomain.com`. You have to use `wildCardSub.modulename.myNewDomain.com`. You can do custom mapping, but not a wildcard mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was looking to set up a similar structure to appspot.com, where each user is just given a subdomain of the main domain. For example userName.myDomain.com. You're saying this is possible right? 
The version name in the .yaml file has to match each subdomain?

Comment: Yes, but not directly on top level, as explained in point 3. above. GAE maps wildcard domains via `version.module.hostname.com`