# Google App Engine Custom Domain SSL with Modules

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-apps

I have multiple modules for my Google App Engine application. Under App Engine Settings from the Developer Console I have added the Custom Domain Names for all my modules.

```
module1.domain.com
module2.domain.com
module3.domain.com
Defaul module is hosted at: www.domain.com
```

All modules have CNAME set to ghs.googlehosted.com and all modules are accessible without SSL.

I installed a Wildcard SSL with SNI through Google Apps under the Google Apps Primary Domain (www.domain.com). My application (through the default module) is now accessible with SSL at https//www.domain.com But none of my modules/subdomains are. How do I get the Wildcard SSL to support the modules?

All modules fail at https//module[1-3].domain.com, while http//module[1-3].domain.com still works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wildcard subdomains on appengine over https on firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722397/wildcard-subdomains-on-appengine-over-https-on-firefox)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate.. that other question is dealing with custom domains.